# How to use a total of a computed column as a value in another query?

Tags: sql

Background :-
I have a scenario where I would like to find out the value of items we have quoted on projects where we have been named as the preferred supplier and also the value of the items we were not named for.

The tables I have at my disposal are dba.lead -> dba.a_quotelne 
The columns that decide whether the items are specified or not are :
"dba"."a_quotelne"."altlineref" If altlineref = 0 then we are not named, if it = 1 we have been named. HOWEVER only the first line of each group of items contains a 1 or 0. The rest are Null.

Example

```
        "leadno"    "lead_desc"     "lineno"    "calc_value"    "altlineref"    "calc_groupingref"
        1           Canary Wharf        1           10          0               1000
        1           Canary Wharf        2           16          Null            1000
        1           Canary Wharf        3           12          Null            1000
        1           Canary Wharf        4           12          1               1001
        1           Canary Wharf        5           13          Null            1001
        2           Rosente Lane        1           14          0               1002
        2           Rosente Lane        2           14          1               1003
        2           Rosente Lane        3           12          Null            1003
        2           Rosente Lane        1           15          1               1004
        2           Rosente Lane        2           267         Null            1004
        2           Rosente Lane        3           298         Null            1004
```

I then used the following code to split the specified and non specified values apart, but I now need a total of each and then somehow only use that computed total in a much larger report.

```
  SELECT "dba"."lead"."leadno",   
     "dba"."lead"."lead_desc",   
     "dba"."a_quotelne"."quoteno",   
     "dba"."a_quotelne"."lineno",   
     "dba"."a_quotelne"."calc_value" * MAX("dba"."a_quotelne"."altlineref") OVER (PARTITION BY "dba"."a_quotelne"."calc_groupingref") AS SPEC_VALUE,   
     "dba"."a_quotelne"."calc_value" - SPEC_VALUE AS NONSPEC_VALUE  
FROM "dba"."a_quotelne",   
     "dba"."lead"  
WHERE ( "dba"."a_quotelne"."leadno" = "dba"."lead"."leadno" ) 
GROUP BY "dba"."a_quotelne"."altlineref",   
     "dba"."a_quotelne"."calc_groupingref",   
     "dba"."a_quotelne"."calc_value",   
     "dba"."a_quotelne"."quoteno",   
     "dba"."lead"."lead_desc",   
     "dba"."lead"."leadno",   
     "dba"."a_quotelne"."lineno"
```

The results I wish to achieve are as follows

```
    "leadno"    "lead_desc"     Nonspec value   Spec value
    1           Canary Wharf            38          25
    2           Rosente Lane            14          606
```

As you are probably aware I am a little out of my depth here, any help would be massively appreciated - and if anyone has a better suggestion on how to split the specified and non specified values apart please include that.

Many thanks in advance

Phil

Comment: Have you tried using the COUNT() function?

Comment: Where would I use said function? I have played with most of the functions to try and solve this. My main problem is when I try to do a SUM(MAX("dba"."a_quotelne"."altlineref") OVER (PARTITION BY "dba"."a_quotelne"."calc_groupingref")) it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is that you have quote lines with `altlineref` and `calc_groupingref` defined on them.  Several rows might have `calc_groupingref` with the same value, but only one has the correct value of `altlineref` (all the other have `NULL` values).

Here is an alternative way to formulate your query.  The inner query just aggregates the quote lines by lead and `calc_groupingref`.  In doing so, it finds the maximum value and the sum of the values.  The outer query then combines this information with `lead`:

```
select l.leadno, l.lead_desc,
       sum(case when maxref = 0 then ql.val end) as NONSPEC_VALUE,
       sum(case when maxref = 1 then ql.val end) as SPEC_VALUE
from dba.lead l join
     (SELECT ql.leadno, sum(ql.calc_value) as val,
             MAX(ql.altlineref) as maxref
      FROM dba.a_quotelne ql
      group by ql.leadno, cal_groupingref
     ) ql 
     on ql.leadno = l.leadno
GROUP BY l.leadno, l.lead_desc;
```

Along the way, I introduced table aliases to make the query easier to understand.

Comment: That is almost perfect, however I have tested it a little and some results were coming back as erroneous, for example there was a quote I tested it on with a total value of 49,885 but the specified and non specified figures it gave me were 46,608 Spec and 6394 Non Spec - is there a possibility that the query could duplicate values as the two figures combined add up to more than the total quote value? - also as a side note the two figures listed appear to be the wrong way round, the larger value should be assigned to the non spec column in this instance...

Comment: @PhilSlade . . . I cannot think of a way that it would *increase* the total value.  If you can, can you edit the question with the data for that example?

Comment: Gordon, thank you for taking the time to help me. After running the answer given by Andiry M and getting the same result as yours, it was apparent that something was up with my data set, and sure enough after some digging I fixed that issue. The code above works perfectly. Again - Many thanks!!

Comment: I didn't try to analyse your solution first because of Phil's initial comment about incorrect results and because I had an idea of my own to suggest. It is only now, when I have thought of suggesting a PIVOT solution, that I realised that a pivot is what your answer does. I mean, the main SELECT's aggregations did look like a normal pivoting process to me at the time but I had my doubts because of how `maxref` was obtained. (As I said, I didn't take a closer look to investigate.) So, good job and +1!

Answer (score 0):

Before joining the two tables, I would replace `altlineref` with `MAX(altlineref) OVER (PARTITION BY calc_groupingref)` in a subquery, so that instead of this row set:

```
altlineref  calc_groupingref
----------  ----------------
0           1000
Null        1000
Null        1000
1           1001
Null        1001
0           1002
1           1003
Null        1003
1           1004
Null        1004
Null        1004
```

I would be joining this one:

```
altlineref  calc_groupingref
----------  ----------------
0           1000
0           1000
0           1000
1           1001
1           1001
0           1002
1           1003
1           1003
1           1004
1           1004
1           1004
```

That way I would be able to reference `altlineref` easily in the outer query without being afraid that the nulls would mess the results for me:

```
SELECT
  l.leadno,
  l.lead_desc,
  nonspec_value = SUM(q.calc_value * (1 - q.altlineref)),
  spec_value    = SUM(q.calc_value *      q.altlineref )
FROM dba.lead AS l
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    leadno,
    altlineref = MAX(altlineref) OVER (PARTITION BY calc_groupingref),
    calc_value
  FROM dba.a_quotelne
) AS q ON l.leadno = q.leadno
GROUP BY
  l.leadno,
  l.lead_desc
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly. I chose the other answer for the accepted method as the processing time was slightly shorter. Many thanks for your help!!